# WooCommerce order status not getting assigned properly for PayPal payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, paypal-sandbox, orders

**Scenario**

I'm using `paypal sandbox` account for payment right now and I've set it up correctly  , the order is getting successfully placed if I use paypal payment while checkout. But the status should be **completed** but its not assigning that.(I'm trying this with virtual product only)

I've already read several articles related to same issue and I only found that if it is set properly then the status should be completed or either I've to set it manually by using code(but is this only way? and is it proper?).

Following are the observations from admin side:

On Order Notes -

```
Payment pending (unilateral). Order status changed from Pending payment to On Hold.
```

Paypal log(only last 3 lines as it was huge) -

```
2019-03-08T11:40:45+00:00 INFO Received valid response from PayPal
2019-03-08T11:40:45+00:00 INFO Found order #9985
2019-03-08T11:40:45+00:00 INFO Payment status: pending
```

Comment: Maybe research over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ SO is specifically about coding, so you'd need to show your [mcve].

Comment: @jdv Wordpress StackExchange is also about coding and **exclusively for Wordpress, but not for plugins**. So **StackOverFlow is the right place for Woocommerce tagged questions**. Both are specifically about coding…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec be that as it may, the woocommerce tag over there is very busy. It would be foolish not to research a "should I code or config" question over there first.

Comment: The busiest is here on StackOverFlow for Woocommerce and other plugins… Plugins related questions on Wordpress StackExchange are off-topic…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec note that I used the word "research". There is no question of topicness, other than it is unclear where a woocommerce config, non-code question would live. No one has said that this Q belongs on WP.SE. But if this is to live here, it ought to have a [mcve] and ask a specific plugin coding question.

Comment: @jdv The best way is too search on web search engines like google as they also take in account StackOverFlow and Wordpress StackExchange threads… Now you are right as both StackOverFlow and Wordpress StackExchange are related to coding.

Answer (score 0):

The typical cause of this is a mismatch between your paypal details.

When you signed up for Sandbox Paypal you we're given a sandbox email address. You must make sure you're using your Sandbox email and not your standard Paypal email address.

You can also try looking in

```
    Woocommerce > Settings > Products > Downloadable Products
```

And make sure you have the grant access after payment box ticked.

http://cld.wthms.co/ZExhMq

Comment: Yes, I'm not using standard Pyapal email address I'm using that merchant one, also the box is ticked too. I just wanted to confirm, Do I've to use the credentials which is provided in Profile tab or NVP/SOAP Sandbox API Credentials?

Comment: Can you try following all the steps laid out in this video. If there are still issues then we can explore them futher I just want to ensure it has been set up correctly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkunOqCMiWc

Comment: Yes, I followed exactly same, created buyer account and tried with that too. But the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was happening because I had created both facilitator and the buyers account separately via https://sandbox.paypal.com in contrast both of these accounts should be created in https://developer.paypal.com > sandbox > accounts.

When I had created the account separately the email address was not getting verified, I think that could be the reason for it not to work also when the user accounts are created from (https://developer.paypal.com > sandbox > accounts) you can see notifications for each account and perform an action accordingly.